# In FTP, can I specify a remote directory using `~username` syntax?

Tags: linux, ftp

I know the ftp username, password, and directory of the source.

I just want to download the whole thing to a new server.

Simple download.

The username is not root. So I wonder how I would specify the directory name? Should I give the `/home/username/public_html` or should I give it as `~username/public_html`

Comment: This is completely dependent on how the server is configured.

Comment: I used cpanel. We got ftp server and stuff.

Comment: all I want is to download a directory to my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### wget

Use `wget` as follow

```
wget --mirror --no-parent --user=<ftpuser> --password=<ftppassword> ftp://server/<directory path>
```

It will download the whole directory recursively.

Option `--no-parent`

> Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.

So the following

```
wget --mirror --no-parent --user=<ftpuser> --password=<ftppassword> ftp://server/home/username/public_html
```

will only download directory structure starting with `public_html`.

### Directory path

You should login ftp server once to confirm the path. Depending on how ftp server is configure, the path may actually start within the home directory. In that case, the directory path will be `/public_html` only.

### Changing Directory Ownership

Change the user and group of the downloaded directory with following command

```
chown -R <user>:<group> public_html
```

If you want to change to user `www-data` and group `www-data`

```
chown -R www-data:www-data public_html
```

You may also want to remove write permission for `others`/`anybody`

```
chmod -R o-w public_html

-R = recursively

Category (can assign multiple without space)
u = user
g = group
o = others = anybody

Add/Remove
"-" sign = remove permission following the sign, from category before the sign
"+" sign = add permission following the sign, to category before the sign

Permission (can assign multiple without space)
r = read permission
w = write permission
x = execute permission

Example
ug+w = add write permission to user and group
ugo-wx = remove write and execute permission from user, group and others
```

Comment: who will own the downloaded file? root?

Comment: Files will be owned by user downloading them. If you use root to download, then yes, root owns them. I added instruction to change ownership after download.

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt
mget ~/public_html
```

This should download everything from `/home/username/public_html` directory.

Comment: what does prompt do?

Comment: By default `mget` runs in interactive mode i.e it will ask you if it is fine to copy over xyz file/dir  and you have to respond with either `y` or `n`.
To turn this feature off, `prompt` command needs to be executed. It toggles the `Interactive Mode` of FTP client.

Comment: will this be recursive?

Comment: Yes, of course. Test it for yourself :)